# Is there any reason to use {% block name %} over {{ self.name() }} in Jinja templating?

Tags: jinja2

I ran into the problem of wanting to reuse the same block of content multiple times in the same base template. This lead me to use the following:

```
<li>
  {% block backup %} {% endblock %}
</li>
...
<li>
  {{ self.backup() }}
</li>
```

Is there any advantage to using `block backup` one time and `self.backup()` for every subsequent time compared to just using `self.backup()` every time? From my very basic testing there is no direct difference on the website. It runs and looks the same with both variants.

The website is just a small internal FAQ at my company so performance is not really a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One use-case where `{% block name %}{% endblock %}` works but `{{ self.name()}}` does not is when templating optional content. Anything designated with `self` has to exist in the page that `extends` it.
Example:

**base.html**

```html
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/reset.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/styles.css"/>
  
  {{ self.stylesheet() }}

</head>
```

If a page `extending` base.html does not contain `{% block stylesheet %}...{% endblock %}` the page will fail to load with a 500 server error when it cannot find the `stylesheet`. This does not happen if it is declared as `{% block stylesheet %}...{% endblock %}` in `base.html`, it just gets skipped.
(The same behaviour can be used with `{% block name %}` by adding the `required` keyword.)